# Scaling dimension and system size

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

I am reading a paper ([Sliding Luttinger liquid phases](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.64.045120)
) which is trying to obtain the scaling dimension of several operators in (condensed matter) field theory.

In this paper, the authors mentioned that (above Eq. [3.7]):

> In order to determine the dimensions of operators, we calculate the leading dependence of correlation functions such $\langle \theta_x^2(r,t) \rangle$ on system size $L$.

Here it seems to me that the scaling dimension of a certain term/operator in the action can be obtained by simply calculating the expectation value of it and extract the *power* law dependence on the system size, I wonder why this is true?

Naively, I think one should do RG to extract the scaling dimension of an operator in the action.